# Permanently hide an item on Interface Builder via code

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, swift3

I have a weird question. Wasn't able to find a solution via search neither in SO nor via google.

I have a `UIView` in my `UIViewController` which is lead by a storyboard.
This `UIView` is set, via Interface Builder, to hidden.

Based on certain logics at some point i need to reveal this `UIView`.

Pretty easy: `myView.isHidden = false`

problem is that each time my `UIViewController` loads, it overrides whatever has happened before -such as un-hiding the view- and set the view to hidden again.

Is there a smart way to permanently hide or should I go for UserDefaults storing the value and loading it in `ViewWillAppear` each time?

Thanks for any possible suggestion.

note: I'm coding in `Swift3` syntax

*******************EDIT*******************

To make it more clear: 
I'm have a bunch of custom pop-ups which sits on a dedicated storyboard file. Each of the pop-ups has a `UIViewController`.

These popups are basically achievements popups. They have 3 stars, all of them hidden by default (via IB properties on the 3 `UIImageView` that they holds).

Along the app, if the user reach a certain kind of achievement, I'll be calling the related UIViewController from that storyboard file and showing (un-hiding) the related achieved star. Just like that.

Main VC:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "AchievementsPopUp", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Category1PopUp")
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

On the related class file, I'm un-hiding via code the star and presenting to the user. Once the user dismiss the popupVC going back to the main one, the "un-hide" property is lost for that UIImageView.
I've solved using a property on UserDefaults which works pretty well.
The problem is that I had to create 15 different properties (5 screens with 3 stars each) and manage the related code which turned to be a little messy :-)
If there are smarter solutions I'll be happy to implement!

Comment: Each time the scene is loaded from the storyboard the properties will be set as per the storyboard.  You will need to write some code in, say, `viewDidLoad` to hide or unhide the view as you need

Comment: thanks @Paulw11 that was exactly what I was about to do as a 'workaround'. But looks like it's not a workaround but a normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Apple's documentation for Preserving and Restoring State](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html).

The preservation and restoration process is mostly automatic, but you need to tell iOS which parts of your app to preserve. The steps for preserving your app’s view controllers are as follows:

1. (Required) Assign restoration identifiers to the view controllers whose configuration you want to preserve; see Tagging View Controllers for Preservation.
2. (Required) Tell iOS how to create or locate new view controller objects at launch time; see Restoring View Controllers at Launch Time.
3. (Optional) For each view controller, store any specific configuration data needed to return that view controller to its original configuration; see Encoding and Decoding Your View Controller’s State.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @picciano.
I'm not 100% sure that's the case I'm describing in my question. State config is more about when your app goes in background or being stopped to prevent memory leaking. When restoring its component (UI too) are rebuilt form where they were based on a restoration point.
In my case I'm never leaving the app. Just loading the same storyboard-->UIViewController more times during the app lifecycle. Maybe my question was not 100% clear, I'll try to edit with some examples.